# String split and count the total sum of strings with number

Tags: jquery, object, text, split, counter

I am trying to string split this long string and cout all the occurrences with suming the number before `x` of same string splits

```
<div id="all">3xOrange;2xBlue;1xRed;1xRed;1xRed;1xOrange;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xOrange;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;51xBlue;51xRed;</div>

<b id="total"></b>
```

I'm struggling with this code:

```
var obj = {};

$("#all").text().split(";").forEach(function(text){
  if (text != ""){
    var part = text.split("x");
    obj[part[1]] = obj[part[1]] != undefined ? obj[part[1]]+1 : parseInt(part[0]);
  }
});
for (key in obj) {
  $("#total").append(obj[key] +"×"+ key + "; ");
}
```

Problem is that al though it theoretically works ,but when the string is too long like the one posted above some of string splits are ignored by suming.
The total sum of `Orange Red and Blue` is incorrect.

[Codepen code here!](http://codepen.io/stefanbr/pen/ozyyax#anon-signup)

Please help , how can I fix this funcionality to sum my string splits properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

First i've `split` on the `;` and in second split ont the `x` and add the first row at the total.

Create an associative array for save each key with total. And loop in this array with `Object.keys(array).forEach(function(key, index) {},array);` method or `for(var key in array){}`

```js
var array = $("#all").text().split(';');
var total=0;
var colorarray = new Array();
$.each(array,function(key,value){
if(value!='')
{
  if(colorarray[value.split("x")[1]]==undefined)
  {
     colorarray[value.split("x")[1]]=0;
  }
  
  var itemnumber = parseInt(value.split("x")[0]);
  colorarray[value.split("x")[1]]+=(itemnumber);
  total+=(itemnumber);
}
});

for(var key in colorarray)
{
  $("#total").append("<div>"+key+" : "+colorarray[key]+"</div>");
};

$("#total").append("<div>total :"+total+"</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all">3xOrange;2xBlue;1xRed;1xRed;1xRed;1xOrange;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xOrange;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;51xBlue;51xRed;</div>

<b id="total"></b>
```

Comment: This actually works very well , but I still need the second part of the string split ,in this case (xOrange, xBlue , xRed) my intend was to get total sum of each orange , blue and red

Comment: Yup you did it :) ! , working like charm , Thank you very much !